# How can I use GPUTree (the shap explainer) on AWS databricks?

Tags: gpu, databricks, shap, aws-databricks

AWS databricks GPU instances seem only to offer the CPU version of the shap library. Following the  [documentation](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/api_examples/explainers/GPUTree.html), I can replace it with the GPU version (finishes without errors). Unfortunately when using it on a single dummy sample, it throws the unhelpful

> ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) Error while
> obtaining a new communication channel

which supposedly is an OOM error - besides that there should be plenty of space and ganglia shows so. I think I am at a dead end here. Any way to get a more useful error message? Other baby steps to try? Or a different approach that would accomplish the same thing (running GPUTree in databricks-AWS)?

Answer (score 0):

> Like the Tree explainer, the GPUTree explainer is specifically designed for tree-based machine learning models, but it is designed to accelerate the computations using NVIDIA GPUs. [source](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/api_examples/explainers/GPUTree.html)

To run it, one needs:

1. `shap` package *installed* on a machine with a GPU
2. Machine *having* a GPU at runtime.

Otherwise, try `KernelExplainer`, which you may find a bit slow

Comment: Can you make a recommendation for an AWS databricks based setup specifically? (which versions and instances to use, environments etc.). I very much suspect a versioning incompatibility between databricks, cuda, shap,... But I am at a loss where to start here, as my attempts have ended in this cryptic error message above. And yes, I do need GPU-TreeShap.

Comment: If you have a GPU in your environment with properly installed drivers, i.e. cuda toolkit, I'd suggest uninstalling the package that doesn't work and then doing something like `pip install git+https://github.com/slundberg/shap`.

Comment: And I doubt it's a versionig problem. You may have some problems with installation/running the package, but your error is a `ConnectException`, which hints me to check network configuration, assuming the package is properly installed.